# Simplicius of Cilicia - Citation System

Tags: aristotle, greeks, translation, presocratics

I am reading the wonderful "The Texts of Early Greek Philosophy" (Daniel W. Graham).

There are frequent excerpts from Simplicius' commentary on Aristotle's Physics.

I would like to look up the excerpts in translations of Simplicius' work (as provided by Bloomsbury press, for example).

The excerpts in Graham's work are cited in this manner - "Simplicius Physics 23. 21-29".

However, the numbering system for the translations of Simplicius' work are of the form "1.3, 1.4, ...", etc., up until 10.

So how can I map Graham's numbering system onto the translation?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but... The text of Simplicius's commentary is organized with ref to Aristotle's book (e.g. *Physics*). Thus, [Simplicius: On Aristotle *Physics* 1.3-4](https://books.google.it/books?id=UAgsAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15) ref to *Phys*, Bk.1, Ch.3-4 (para 186a4-13). See also [Simplicis' *Works*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicius_of_Cilicia#Works_in_English_translation)

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA ! That form of citation definitely makes sense to me. I wish the excerpts in Graham were expressed the same way :(

Answer (score 1):

The citation numbers used by Graham apparently refer to section numbers in the original Simplicius text. In the Bloomsbury translations, those section numbers (of the original Simplicius text) are written just to the left or right of the main block of text.

The Bloomsbury translation of Simplicius' commentary on Aristotle's Physics 1.3-4, for example, includes sections 102-179. While the Bloomsbury translation of Simplicius' commentary on Aristotle's Physics 1.5-9, on the other hand, includes sections 179-208.[image: Example]